# Get caret position in editable div IE8

Tags: javascript, json

I have my way of getting the selected data in my editable div for all browsers except IE8.

can someone help me

this is what I have now

```
get_selection: function () {
        var range;
        var bookmark;
        var length = this._displayText().length;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == this._display) {
                return { start: range.startOffset, end: range.endOffset, text: this._displayText().substr(range.startOffset, range.endOffset - range.startOffset) };
            }
        }
        else if (document.selection) {
//solution for IE8 and lower
        }
        return { start: 0, end: 0, text: "" };
    },
```

this._display is my editable div element.
this._displayText() will return textContent from my display element. I made a sepperate function for this because textcontent is not supported in IE8 and I use innerText for IE8.

I already tried some solution which I found on google but nothing gave me the start and end position of the carret.

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 and before used its own selection mechanism not compatible with the standard. For more information read [selection object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx) and [TextRange object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872(v=vs.85).aspx) at MSDN.

To get selected range use the following code:

```
var Rng = document.selection.createRange();
```

Than you can get the selected text if any using `Rng.text`, screen coordinates of the selected area using `Rng.getClientRects()`, etc.

Comment: what you tell me I already know. you helped me a litle but you didn't really answer my question. I still don't know how to get the start and end position of my carret in IE8

Answer (score 0):

ok. this is a solution I just found which works perfect. I post it to help others who need it to.

```
get_selection: function () {
        var range;
        var preRange;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == this._display) {
                return { start: range.startOffset, end: range.endOffset, text: range.toString() };
            }
        }
        else if (document.selection) {
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            preRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            preRange.moveToElementText(this._display);
            preRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
            return { start: preRange.text.length, end: preRange.text.length + range.text.length, text: range.text };
        }
        return { start: 0, end: 0, text: "" };
    },
```